# JNI undefined symbol

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I had a problem executing a c method from java (jni) .

The content of the CMakeLists.txt is the follow :

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/home/runix/instalers/stasm4.1.0")
set(STASM_DIR ..)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
 include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

find_package(STASM REQUIRED)
if(STASM_FOUND)
  include_directories(${STASM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

find_package(JNI)
if(JNI_FOUND)
   include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR} ${STASM_LINK_DIRS} ${JNI_LINK_DIRS})

SET(LIBS ${STASM_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS}  ${JNI_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_XX_FLAGS} -fPIC ")
SET(EXECUTABLES minimal)
FOREACH(var ${EXECUTABLES})
add_executable(${var} ${var}.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${var} ${LIBS})
ADD_LIBRARY(ctest SHARED ${var} ${var}.cpp)
ENDFOREACH(var)
```

The code compile and I can execute the executable correctly ( As you can see in the CMakeLists I generate the dynamic library and a executable )

But when I try to execute the code from java it throws an exception :

java -Djava.library.path=. StasmJNI

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/runix/instalers/stasm4.1.0/external/libctest.so: /home/runix/instalers/stasm4.1.0/external/libctest.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:844)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1051)
    at StasmJNI.<clinit>(StasmJNI.java:3)
```

If I remove all code from the c function java works correctly and I don't know what its the problem.

Java code :

```
public class StasmJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ctest"); /* (2) */
    }

    public StasmJNI() {

    }

    public native float[] getPoints(String path);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new StasmJNI().getPoints("Prueba").length);
    }
}
```

c code :

StasmJNI.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class StasmJNI */

#ifndef _Included_StasmJNI
#define _Included_StasmJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     StasmJNI
 * Method:    getPoints
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)[F
 */
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_StasmJNI_getPoints
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

StasmJNI.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "stasm_lib.h"
#include "StasmJNI.h"

void error(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    printf("Stasm version %s: %s %s\n", stasm_VERSION, s1, s2);
    exit(1);
}
using namespace cv;

float* getLandmarks(char * const path, int * size) {

   if (!stasm_init("../data", 0 ))
        error("stasm_init failed: ", stasm_lasterr());

    cv::Mat_<unsigned char> img(cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));

    if (!img.data)
        error("Cannot load", path);

    if (!stasm_open_image((const char*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, path,
                          1 , 10 ))
        error("stasm_open_image failed: ", stasm_lasterr());

    int foundface;
    float landmarks[2 * 20];// stasm_NLANDMARKS]; // x,y coords (note the 2)


    int nfaces = 0; 
    int iters  = 0;
    while (iters++ < 2)
    {
        if (!stasm_search_auto(&foundface, landmarks))
             error("stasm_search_auto failed: ", stasm_lasterr());

        if (!foundface)
            break;      // note break

        stasm_force_points_into_image(landmarks, img.cols, img.rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < stasm_NLANDMARKS; i++)
            img(cvRound(landmarks[i*2+1]), cvRound(landmarks[i*2])) = 255;

        nfaces++;
    }
    if(nfaces == 1) 
    *size = stasm_NLANDMARKS * 2;
    else
    *size = 0;
    return landmarks;
}

JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_StasmJNI_getPoints
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject object, jstring path) {
     int size = 0;
     getLandmarks(path2, &size);
 jfloatArray result;
     result = env->NewFloatArray(size);

return result;
}


int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    char* const path = "minimal2.jpg";
     IplImage* ipl = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    Mat temp = ipl;
    cv::imwrite(path, temp);
    getLandmarks(path, &size);
    printf("the size %d\n", size);
}
```

(NOTE THE C++ CODE USE OPENCV AND STASM)
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT 1 : output of nm --demangle libctest.so

```
0000000000204210 d DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
00000000000026be T Java_StasmJNI_getPoints
0000000000203e08 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000203fe8 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U _Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0
00000000000023cc T getLandmarks(char*, int*)
000000000000238c T error(char const*, char const*)
0000000000002845 W cvRound(double)
000000000000329c r stasm_NLANDMARKS
                 U cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)
000000000000314c W cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<unsigned char>(cv::Mat_<unsigned char> const&)
000000000000314c W cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<unsigned char>(cv::Mat_<unsigned char> const&)
00000000000030c0 W cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<unsigned char>(cv::Mat_<unsigned char>&)
00000000000030c0 W cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray<unsigned char>(cv::Mat_<unsigned char>&)
                 U cv::Mat::deallocate()
0000000000002bde W cv::Mat::MSize::MSize(int*)
0000000000002bde W cv::Mat::MSize::MSize(int*)
0000000000002bf8 W cv::Mat::MStep::MStep()
0000000000002bf8 W cv::Mat::MStep::MStep()
0000000000002c52 W cv::Mat::MStep::operator[](int)
0000000000002b10 W cv::Mat::release()
                 U cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)
000000000000287a W cv::Mat::initEmpty()
                 U cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)
000000000000290a W cv::Mat::Mat()
000000000000290a W cv::Mat::Mat()
0000000000002950 W cv::Mat::~Mat()
0000000000002950 W cv::Mat::~Mat()
0000000000002990 W cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)
0000000000002d3a W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::Mat_(cv::Mat const&)
0000000000002d3a W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::Mat_(cv::Mat const&)
0000000000002ca2 W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::~Mat_()
0000000000002ca2 W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::~Mat_()
0000000000002eb8 W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::operator=(cv::Mat const&)
0000000000002da2 W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::operator()(int, int)
00000000000031a2 W cv::Size_<int>::Size_()
00000000000031a2 W cv::Size_<int>::Size_()
                 U cv::imread(std::string const&, int)
                 U cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)
                 U cv::fastFree(void*)
0000000000002c74 W JNIEnv_::NewFloatArray(int)
000000000000311c W __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)
0000000000003198 W __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::new_allocator()
0000000000003198 W __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::new_allocator()
0000000000003112 W __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::~new_allocator()
0000000000003112 W __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::~new_allocator()
0000000000002bb4 W cv::Mat::type() const
0000000000002c30 W cv::Mat::MStep::operator[](int) const
0000000000002bca W cv::Mat::depth() const
                 U cv::Mat::reshape(int, int, int const*) const
                 U cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const
00000000000030b0 W cv::Mat_<unsigned char>::type() const
                 U std::allocator<char>::allocator()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::allocator<char>::~allocator()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
00000000000030f8 W std::allocator<int>::allocator()
00000000000030f8 W std::allocator<int>::allocator()
000000000000303c W std::allocator<int>::~allocator()
000000000000303c W std::allocator<int>::~allocator()
                 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@@GLIBCXX_3.4
000000000000313e W void std::_Destroy_aux<true>::__destroy<int*>(int*, int*)
0000000000002ffe W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl()
0000000000002ffe W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl()
0000000000002dda W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::~_Vector_impl()
0000000000002dda W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::~_Vector_impl()
0000000000003056 W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long)
0000000000002e80 W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_get_Tp_allocator()
0000000000002df4 W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base()
0000000000002df4 W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base()
0000000000002e0e W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base()
0000000000002e0e W std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base()
0000000000002cbc W std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()
0000000000002cbc W std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()
0000000000002cd6 W std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
0000000000002cd6 W std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
000000000000308a W void std::_Destroy<int*>(int*, int*)
0000000000002e8e W void std::_Destroy<int*, int>(int*, int*, std::allocator<int>&)
                 U vtable for cv::_InputArray
                 U vtable for cv::_OutputArray
0000000000203e00 d __gthread_active_p()::__gthread_active_ptr
                 U operator delete(void*)@@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000203de0 d __CTOR_END__
0000000000203dd8 d __CTOR_LIST__
0000000000203df0 d __DTOR_END__
0000000000203de8 d __DTOR_LIST__
00000000000039b8 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000203df8 d __JCR_END__
0000000000203df8 d __JCR_LIST__
0000000000204218 A __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000031d0 t __do_global_ctors_aux
00000000000022e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000204208 d __dso_handle
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3
0000000000204218 A _edata
0000000000204228 A _end
0000000000003208 T _fini
0000000000001e80 T _init
00000000000022c0 t call_gmon_start
0000000000204218 b completed.6531
                 U cvCreateCameraCapture
                 U cvQueryFrame
0000000000204220 b dtor_idx.6533
                 U exit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000002360 t frame_dummy
                 U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w pthread_cancel
                 U stasm_VERSION
                 U stasm_force_points_into_image
                 U stasm_init
                 U stasm_lasterr
                 U stasm_open_image
                 U stasm_search_auto
```

Edit 2 : output of ldd

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff693fe000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd2a639d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd2a609d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd2a5da0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd2a5b83000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd2a597b000)
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fd2a572a000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fd2a5502000)
libtiff.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 (0x00007fd2a529e000)
libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007fd2a5046000)
libv4l1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0 (0x00007fd2a4e40000)
libavcodec.so.53 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53 (0x00007fd2a402f000)
libavformat.so.53 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.53 (0x00007fd2a3d2e000)
libavutil.so.51 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.51 (0x00007fd2a3b0e000)
libswscale.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.2 (0x00007fd2a38c8000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd2a36b1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd2a32f1000)
libv4l2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0 (0x00007fd2a30e5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd2a65d5000)
libvpx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libvpx.so.1 (0x00007fd2a2e3f000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fd2a2970000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fd2a2744000)
libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007fd2a2506000)
libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007fd2a22eb000)
libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007fd2a20d2000)
libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fd2a1e1e000)
libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007fd2a1c10000)
libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007fd2a19fa000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fd2a17e9000)
libv4lconvert.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0 (0x00007fd2a1574000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fd2a136c000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007fd2a10f1000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd2a0eed000)
```

EDIT 3:

I load the output of ldd but the program crash again when load ctest library 
with undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE.

```
System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6");
        System.load("/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2");
        System.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6");
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            //Program crash here
            System.loadLibrary("ctest");
```

SOLVED : Here is my solution,

Compile first into static library ( CMakeLists.txt)

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
  ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR}
)

SET(STASM_BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

SET(OBJ_STASM
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/asm.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/classicdesc.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/convshape.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/err.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/eyedet.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/eyedist.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/faceroi.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/hat.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/hatdesc.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/landmarks.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/misc.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/pinstart.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/print.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/shape17.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/shapehacks.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/shapemod.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/startshape.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/stasm.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/stasm_lib.cpp
)

SET(OBJ_MOD1
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/MOD_1/facedet.cpp
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/MOD_1/initasm.cpp
)

include_directories(${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm)
include_directories(${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/MOD_1)

SET(STASM_INCLUDE_DIRS 
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm
${STASM_BASE_DIR}/stasm/MOD_1
)

SET(LIBS  ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_XX_FLAGS} -fPIC ")

set(STASM_LIBS stasm)
add_library(${STASM_LIBS} ${OBJ_MOD1} ${OBJ_STASM})
target_link_libraries(${STASM_LIBS} ${LIBS})


SET(EXECUTABLES minimal minimal2)
FOREACH(var ${EXECUTABLES})
add_executable(${var} apps/${var}.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${var} ${STASM_LIBS} ${LIBS})
ENDFOREACH(var)



#**************************************************************************************************
# Generate batch files for examples
#**************************************************************************************************
#setup Config.cmake
configure_file(STASMConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/STASMConfig.cmake" @ONLY)

INSTALL(
FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/STASMConfig.cmake 
DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/cmake/ 
COMPONENT dev)
```

Extract static library from .a

ar -x static_library_name

Compile to a shared library

gcc -shared -o libctest2.so minimal.cpp.o -Wl,-rpath, /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so $PWD/libstasm.so

Thanks for https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823225/graham-griffiths user!

Comment: What is the name of your library file? You trying to load in JAVA "ctest"...

Comment: It's complaining about an undefined symbol _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE
 - where is that coming from?  Does your code have 'InputArray' anywhere?  You can use linux tool 'nm' to list all symbols defined in your library e.g. like this nm --demangle /usr/lib64/libnsmsg.so it will show you which symbols are defined, and which are not

Comment: my library name is libctest.so, but I think that the problem ain't loading the library because if I remove the code of the method and put for example printf("hi from c"); the code works correctly and java don't throws any exception.

Comment: I think that the symbol _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE is used by opencv or stasm. But if I execute the executable ( not from java ) works correctly and its the same code only change that one is a dynamic library and other an executable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the executable knows where to find its libraries from, and loads them on startup. Try running "ldd my_executable_name" - it shows where the libraries are found when running the executable

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search for _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE shows that it should be part of library libopencv_core.so - you will have to make sure this is loaded in Java before calling your JNI function.

So, add this line below and make sure the library is available somewhere Java can find it :

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_core");
```

EDIT : by the way you can see the references to _InputArray in your output from nm, with a U for undefined (if you run it without the --demangle option, it will print the 'mangled' name which will exactly match the undefined symbol it complains about).  What this means - your code refers to some opencv types / functions - the symbols are left undefined in your library file, so to run properly it needs the opencv library file to be loaded too.

You'll probably need to do the same thing with your stasm library too.

Comment: it fails to load opencv library?

Comment: Thanks! but it doesn't work, I try loading opencv library (EDIT 3) but it doesn't solve the problem and I'm sure that Opencv is loaded correctly because I can use Opencv objects.

Comment: crikey, you shouldn't have to load all of those system libraries.  But - I don't see opencv in the list of loaded libraries?

Comment: if you use nm to inspect the opencv library, you will see the _InputArray defined there (it will show a 'T' for text i.e. defined in code/text) next to it.

Comment: what do you mean you can use opencv objects?  I am not so sure that the opencv .so file has been loaded

Comment: maybe you can just change the way it builds your dynamic library to link directly to opencv, like in the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558909/jni-symbol-lookup-error-in-shared-library-on-linux

Comment: I include opencv with System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); but I also check with System.loadLibrary("opencv_core"); and get the same error..

Comment: Thanks!! I solve the problem with the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558909/jni-symbol-lookup-error-in-shared-library-on-linux answer. thanks so much for the answers!!